# SharePoint displaying non-english language content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, language-pack

How can I have my custom content translated to non-English language in a site collection? The language pack installation like Arabic will translate the SharePoint defaults to Arabic but how can I change the custom content created in lists or inserted in content editor web part to Arabic? Do I need to create separate sites one for english and the other for Arabic or SharePoint will provide auto switching of these languages through some OOTB features?